# CakePHP: can't get models to work

Tags: cakephp, php

Im really new to cakePHP, and I more or less understand the controllers, and views as I worked with a MVC framework before. However, the models and naming conventions in cakePHP seem to be different from what I've used before. the one's I've used; you call various functions such as select, and insert, with the fields and such you want, and then execute the query. Essentially you build your own query. I'm trying to figure out how to use models in cakePHP, and as I understand it, if I have a controller in /controllers/users_controller.php with the contents:

```
<?php
class UsersController extends AppController{
    var $name = 'Users';

    var $helpers = array ('Html','Form');

    public function login(){
        $this->set('msg', 'Login PAGE!!!! YAY!!!!!!!!!');
        $this->set('MT', $this->Users->find('all'));
    }
}
```

then it should automatically have the Model, Users, in models/users.php available to it right? Therefore the variable $MT can be echoed on the page.

The contents on Users.php are:

```
<?php

class Users extends AppModel{
    var $name = 'Users';
}
```

The problem I'm having though seems to be:

```
Undefined property: UsersController::$Users [APP\controllers\users_controller.php
```

and thus leads to:

```
Call to a member function find() on a non-object in app\controllers\users_controller.php
```

I'm following the tutorial at http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Tutorials-Examples/Blog.html for cakePHP 1.3 running on a WAMP server. Any advice you can give would be appreciated! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your model name:

```
class Users extends AppModel{
...
```

to

```
class User extends AppModel{
...
```

and:

```
$this->set('MT', $this->Users->find('all'));
```

to

```
$this->set('MT', $this->User->find('all'));
```

Comment: my table name is users though? Will that matter?

Comment: @Samuraisoulification model name User will be tied to database table called users, so yes changing that should work..!

Comment: read it in the same cookbook for which you've posted the link in your question.. see: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Tutorials-Examples/Blog.html#create-a-post-model

Comment: I just tried it and the only change is that i know get a error message:  SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for

Comment: after reading it I renamed the file to user.php as well.

Comment: @Samuraisoulification see my updated answer, you need to use $this->User instead of $this->Users in find('all') part as well..

Comment: Yeah, just figured that out myself! Thanks a lot! I was about to go insane cause of this. :P